# My function keeps returning 0 instead of the actual value

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int arredonda (double x)
{
    int arredondado;
    if (x - (int)x >= 0.5)
        arredondado = (int)x + 1;
    else
        arredondado = (int)x;
    return arredondado;
}

int main()
{
    double num;
    scanf("%f", &num);
    printf("%d", arredonda(num));
    return 0;
}
```

This is a function that rounds a number to upper or to lower depending of the decimal part. The problem is that it keeps returning 0 with all values.

Comment: Does [how-to-round-floating-point-numbers-to-the-nearest-integer-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570934/how-to-round-floating-point-numbers-to-the-nearest-integer-in-c) helps you?

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile!  Here is the compiler message: *untitled2.c:16:13: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double *’ [-Wformat=]*

Answer (score 2):

`%lf` must be used to input a `double`.

Make sure to enable your compiler's warnings!

```
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:16:13: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double *’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%f", &num);
            ~^   ~~~~
            %lf
```

I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` with gcc and clang.

---

As for the rounding itself, there is a better solution: [`round` from math.h](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/round).