# Rounding of binary floating point number's mantissa

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding, precision

Consider I have mantissa of single precision floating point number (form `1.01001...` (23 bit after point)).

I need to determine algorithm of rounding to the nearest even number.

My guess is: if mantissa's last bit is `0` then we return number without changes, otherwise I need to add (or subtract if number is negative) `0.000...01` (23 bits after the point). Is it right?

Comment: That can't be done. Also need the exponent

Comment: @ikegami What do i need to do with it?

Comment: Need to figure out where the decimal point really is. Then you took to its right. 0.5 is 0b0.1, so if what's on the right is less than 0b0.1, round down. Round up if it's more. Round to even if it's equal. An even number will have a 0 to the left of the point, and an odd will have a 1.

Comment: Do you mean the nearest even integer? If yes, what are the nearest even integers of `3` and `5`? Both `4`, since it is "more even" than `2` and `6`? Do you need to cover the entire possible input range?

Comment: Here is a related question which you could apply to `0.5f*x` and then multiply the result by `2.0f`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570934/how-to-round-floating-point-numbers-to-the-nearest-integer-in-c